# Facebook Graph API get USER token instead of APP token (phonegap)

Tags: facebook, api, cordova

I'm trying to implement facebook connect in Adobe PhoneGap through the Graph API but apparently I'm getting back an "App" token instead of a "User" token. This causes for my app to disallow any additional users connecting onto it, which is not the point of course.

I have notice this as no matter what user I use for logging in, the access_token returned is always the same.

I'm using the following URL to authenticate:

```
 var authorize_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?";
    authorize_url += "client_id=" + fb_clientid;
    authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + fb_redirect_uri;
    authorize_url += "&display=" + fb_display;
    authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream"
```

And to get the authorisation token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+fb_clientid+'&client_secret='+fb_secret+'&code='+fbCode+'&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html'
```

I presume the problem lies with the second url (secret being passed indicates it's an app token) but then how do I get the user token?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook [Connect plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/), instead of crafting the login procedure manually. It provides better usability as it is integrated with the Facebook native application or the iOS 6 Facebook functionality.

Comment: The problem with that is that when the user does not have the native facebook application installed, the login redirects to the browser. I have tried using this approach (http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/) to get it to redirect into the Childbrowser plugin, but I cannot get it to function. Any ideas?

Comment: The plugin handles also the case when the user does not have the Facebook application installed on the device. If you follow the instructions, your application registers a custom URL (e.g. fb{yourAppId}://) and you are redirected back to the app when the login completes in browser.

Comment: Yes i know I have all of that working, but I do not want to leave the app. I do not want the browser to be opened, I want the Childbrowser plugin to handle that part, so they stay "in the app", but because the FB plugin calls a urls programmatically somewhere the code on the supplied link does not work. If I could just get it to open in the Childbrowser plugin when they don't have the app installed, it would be complete

Comment: opening the browser or the facebook application gives user the confidence that your app does not "touch" the username and the password. you loose that when you handle the login procedure with the child browser.

Comment: Yet my client does not want the browser to open so I have no choice but to use the Childbrowser, because they believe the opposite is true: the user loses confidence in the application because it "breaks" and goes to the browser. Is there any way I can force the Childbrowser to handle the login request?

Comment: Ayame how did you manage to the facebook connect plugin to work with the adobe build + phonegap? I cannot get it to work. Can you send me your config.xml + an example javascript/html page to andyarmstrong@hotmail.co.uk?